# is it possible to add an index in between two indexes of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': [30, 40, 30, 40, 30, 30, 20, 25],
                   'Height': [120, 162, 120, 120, 120, 72, 120, 81]})
modDfObj = df.append({'Age' : 25, 'Height':172,} , ignore_index=True) 

modDfObj
```

"""Is it possible to add one row between two rows, can we add one more index between two index"""

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Comment: hi @jezrael this is not the perfect answer, this solution is replacing the index values, but i want to add new values without replacing old one

Comment: So use `pd.concat([df.iloc[:2], line, df.iloc[3:]], ignore_index=True)`

Comment: this one also replaces the index values

Comment: got the point,
df2 = pd.concat([df.iloc[:3], line, df.iloc[3:]]).reset_index(drop=True),
"df.iloc[3:]]).reset_index(drop=True)"  this,
after putting line, reset_index() should be there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': [30, 40, 30, 40, 30, 30, 20, 25],
                   'Height': [120, 162, 120, 120, 120, 72, 120, 81]},
                  index=['Jane', 'Jane', 'Aaron', 'Penelope', 'Jaane', 'Nicky',
                         'Armour', 'Ponting'])
line = pd.DataFrame({"Age": 33, "Height": 130}, index=[2])
df2 = pd.concat([df.iloc[:2], line, df.iloc[2:]]).reset_index(drop=True)
df2
```

"""Got the expected ouput"""